# Querying resources in a relationship chain in SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql

I'm new to SPARQL and I'm trying to fetch some results from triples in a SQL join fashion.

e.g. I'm looking for the ID of the object a certain image belongs to, and the ID of the author of the object, and so on.

RDF relations are defined like this:

```
<image> <isResourceOf> <object>
<person> <isAuthorOf> <object>
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT ?o ?a from <#ri> 
WHERE {
  {<myns:myImageID> <myns:isResourceOf> ?o}
  UNION
  {?a <myns:isAuthorOf> ?o}
}
```

But this fetches all the authors, since the two `?o` variables are not bound.

How do I get to match the authors ONLY for the first match set?

Thanks

gm

EDIT:

More complete example:

```
PREFIX aic: <http://mydomain.org/definitions/1.0/fedora/3#>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  <info:fedora/AICTEST:DOResImg-G38562> aic:isResourceOf ?o . 
  ?a aic:isAuthorOf ?o .
}
```

No results.

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  <info:fedora/AICTEST:DOResImg-G38562> aic:isResourceOf ?o . 
}
```

Results (CSV):

```
"o"
AICTEST:DOArtObj-1946.479
```

With this:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?a aic:isAuthorOf ?o .
}
```

Results:

```
"a","o"
info:fedora/AICTEST:DOAgent-35729,info:fedora/AICTEST:DOArtObj-1946.479
info:fedora/AICTEST:DOAgent-35729,AICTEST:DOObjSet-1946.494
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Mulgara. I'm not sure how exactly Mulgara implements SPARQL, so there might be a different behavior in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you would call a join in SQL is simply expressed as a list of basic graph patterns in SPARQL. No `UNION` is necessary:

```
 SELECT ?o ?a 
 WHERE { 
         <myns:myImageId> <myns:isResourceOf> ?o .
         ?a <myns:isAuthorOf> ?o .
 }
```

That's all there is to it. The way to think of SPARQL is as specifying a "graph template" on your data. Everything that exactly matches the template is a result of the query. So the above query will give you all things that `<myns:myImageId>` is a resource of ( = `?o`), and for each of those, all authors (`?a`).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. That would retrieve each record that matches both conditions (AND operator), in fact it returns an empty set. Am I missing something?

Comment: The query not returning anyhing can be caused by a number of things, but the most common mistake is that one or more of the URIs used in the query is incorrect. This seems likely in your example as `<myns:myImageId>` looks more like a prefixed name than a full URI, yet you've put angle brackets around it to indicate it is a full URI. Try removing the angle brackets (and if you do that, you'll need to a PREFIX declaration for the prefix `myns:` to your query).

Comment: This is a simplified version of the actual query, which is fully prefixed. If I only use the first condition on the query, I get some results. With only the second one, I get different results. With your solution I get none. With UNION I get both sets.

Comment: @gattumarrudu then I can only speculate that your data does not have an author linked to `<myns:myImageId>` via an object `?o`.

Comment: Ok, I see my mistake. I omitted the prefix in some relationships, which I thought was optional. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This question duplicates [http://answers.semanticweb.com//questions/23912/fetching-chained-relationships-with-sparql-mulgara](https://web.archive.org/web/20130806125625/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/23912/fetching-chained-relationships-with-sparql-mulgara)

As I said there, I strongly suspect there's something wrong with the namespace prefix definition in your original query, and possibly in your simplified versions as well, given that you're getting errors if the cURIes are not angle-bracket-wrapped.

I suggest that you present complete information to us; else, we will be unable to usefully advise you.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the right relation chain to work:

```
PREFIX aic: <http://mydomain.org/definitions/1.0/fedora/3#>
PREFIX fedora-rels-ext: <info:fedora/fedora-system:def/relations-external#>

SELECT ?o ?a ?p ?s
FROM <#ri>
WHERE {
  <info:fedora/AICTEST:DOResImg-G38562> aic:isResourceOf ?o . 
  OPTIONAL { 
    ?a aic:isAuthorOf ?o .
    OPTIONAL { 
      ?p aic:isBirthplaceOf ?a 
    } . 
  } . 
  OPTIONAL { 
    ?o fedora-rels-ext:isPartOf ?s .
  }
}
```

Results (CSV):

```
"o","a","p","s"
info:fedora/AICTEST:DOArtObj-1946.479,info:fedora/AICTEST:DOAgent-35729,info:fedora/AICTEST:DOPlace-Meissen,AICTEST:DOObjSet-1946.494
```